# Array - join and toString calls return an empty string after toLocaleString call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm not getting the point why calls to the `join` and `toString` methods on an Array object return an empty string after a call to `toLocaleString`:

```
let A = [1, 2, 3];
A.toString(); => "1,2,3"
A.join(); => "1,2,3"
A => (3) [1, 2, 3]
A.toLocaleString(); => ""
A.toString(); => ""
A.join(); => ""
A => (3) [1, 2, 3]
```

I'm trying on Google Chrome 73.0.3683.103, on Firefox I don't experience the same issue.

Comment: what is `A => (3) [1, 2, 3]` doing?

Comment: @brk it's just what you get from the Chrome console if you just type the name of the variable.

Comment: @31py I'll report a bug issue to the Google Chrome team.

Comment: @zer0uno -- This works fine in chrome canary. This would be fixed in next Chrome release. You may want to see the [bug details](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=940373&q=tolocalestring&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=940373)

To fix this issue, you can use this way:

```
[...A].toLocaleString();

//or

[].concat(A).toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: @Barmar This is a bug